# Use prediction as feature for a decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, tfidf

I'm working at classifying documents according to their content.

First I built a decision tree model that gives 90% of goods results.

Then I tried a TFIDF/SVC approach which also gives 90% of good results.

So now i'd like to combine both. My first thought was to add the prediction of TFIDF/SVC as a feature of the decision tree.

I saw this post about [bagging/stacking/boosting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/bagging-boosting-and-stacking-in-machine-learning). For me, adding the feature to the decision tree is equivalent to stacking. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Stacking is essentially feeding the predictions of the base learners to a meta learner. Sort of like a model of the models. Here's a good explanation of that.

[Bagging,Boosting and Stacking](https://medium.com/@rrfd/boosting-bagging-and-stacking-ensemble-methods-with-sklearn-and-mlens-a455c0c982de)